SumoLogic - Get count of each value in a json array
I have a field that's a json array. For example, here's three records:
["apple", "orange", "kiwi"]
["apple"]
["apple", "kiwi"]

How do I get the total count of each value? The above example should result in:
fruits  _count
apple    3
kiwi     2
orange   1

